How can I use the GitLab API to get detailed time tracking for a specific issue or task?
I found only such a method in the official GitLab documentation.
GET /projects/:id/issues/:issue_iid/time_stats

{
  "human_time_estimate": "2h",
  "human_total_time_spent": "1h",
  "time_estimate": 7200,
  "total_time_spent": 3600
}

But I need a detailed report. As in this screenshot.
I'm sorry for the blurring. This is a screenshot from the corporate GitLab.


If anyone wants to get this through a simpler query than this answer, you can use this one (you can try it with GraphiQL on your gitlab instance.
query {
  group(fullPath: "GROUP_NAME") {
    issues {
      nodes {
        title
        iid
        timelogs(first: 100000) {
          nodes {
            summary
            timeSpent
            spentAt
            user {
              username
            }
            
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

The answer looks like this:
{
  "data": {
    "group": {
      "issues": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "title": "Issue 2",
            "iid": "2",
            "timelogs": {
              "nodes": [
                {
                  "summary": "",
                  "timeSpent": 72000,
                  "spentAt": "2024-05-23T11:18:58Z",
                  "user": {
                    "username": "adrienpacificopro"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "title": "Issue 1",
            "iid": "1",
            "timelogs": {
              "nodes": [
                {
                  "summary": "A quelle heure va être mis le spent at",
                  "timeSpent": 1320,
                  "spentAt": "2024-05-04T22:00:00Z",
                  "user": {
                    "username": "adrienpacificopro"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "summary": "Now",
                  "timeSpent": 120,
                  "spentAt": "2024-05-23T11:16:26Z",
                  "user": {
                    "username": "adrienpacificopro"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "summary": "Ceci est un très long summary pour voir ce qu'il en est de la vie des poissons d'eau douce ! Mais on sait jamais ce qu'il peut se passer deans la vie, n'est-ce pas ?è!!!!!",
                  "timeSpent": 115200,
                  "spentAt": "2024-05-23T11:07:56Z",
                  "user": {
                    "username": "adrienpacificopro"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

Then, you can easily transform it to a dataframe (or export it to excel), and filter it by user, issue, date range, and so on.
### Copy paste the output and assign it to data, or integrate it trough api calls
df = pd.json_normalize(data['issues']['nodes'], record_path=['timelogs', 'nodes'], meta=['title', 'iid'])

Result:



summary
timeSpent
spentAt
user.username
title
iid





72000
2024-05-23T11:18:58Z
adrienpacificopro
Issue 2
2


A quelle heure va être mis le spent at
1320
2024-05-04T22:00:00Z
adrienpacificopro
Issue 1
1


Now
120
2024-05-23T11:16:26Z
adrienpacificopro
Issue 1
1


Ceci est un très long summary pour voir ce qu'il en est de la vie des poissons d'eau douce ! Mais on sait jamais ce qu'il peut se passer deans la vie, n'est-ce pas ?è!!!!!
115200
2024-05-23T11:07:56Z
adrienpacificopro
Issue 1
1




After searching for more, I found a section about graphql queries in the official documentation.
With the help of a combination of some miracle and luck, I managed to get such a request:
POST https://holivarius.ru/gitlab/api/graphql?access_token=`your-access-token`
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "operationName": "issueTimeTracking",
  "variables": {
    "iid": "`your-issue-iid`",
    "fullPath": "`your-project-full-path`"
  },
  "query": "query issueTimeTracking($fullPath: ID!, $iid: String) {\n  workspace: project(fullPath: $fullPath) {\n    id\n    issuable: issue(iid: $iid) {\n      ...IssueTimeTrackingFragment\n      humanTimeEstimate\n      timeEstimate\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment IssueTimeTrackingFragment on Issue {\n  __typename\n  id\n  humanTotalTimeSpent\n  totalTimeSpent\n  timelogs {\n    nodes {\n      ...TimelogFragment\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment TimelogFragment on Timelog {\n  __typename\n  id\n  timeSpent\n  user {\n    id\n    name\n    __typename\n  }\n  spentAt\n  note {\n    id\n    body\n    __typename\n  }\n  summary\n  userPermissions {\n    adminTimelog\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"
}

In which the following things need to be replaced:

your-access-token - to your access token.
your-issue-iid - to the ID of your issue in the project.
your-project-full-path - to the full path of your project.

PS: This method is not very reliable, but that's all I found.
Therefore, if someone knows a better way or can explain how it works, then please write your answer or comment on my answer.
